# Pre-loading MP3 Audio URLs in Lambda (Alexa Skill)

Tags: audio, https, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

Using this [Amazon-provided library](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs), I am working on an alexa skill that plays a queue of short mp3 files.  The code that triggers the audio looks like this:

```
this.response.audioPlayerPlay('REPLACE_ALL', mp3HttpsUrl, mp3HttpsUrl, null, 0);
```

(function documentation [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/blob/fdf4a04c853bbe38dc6aecfe16117a07c4a27948/ask-sdk-v1adapter/lib/responseBuilderShim.ts#L107))

This is further invoked during the `PlaybackNearlyFinished` audio event handler to queue up the next audio file URL.

It works fine, but there is about a 3~4 second gap between the audio playback. I would like to reduce the gap, and have as-close-to-uninterrupted playback as possible.

In a browser setting, this would be achieved by pre-loading to cache before the time to play has arrive; when the URL finally does gets called to play, the browser just plays it from local storage, delivering a experience with virtually no lag.

How can this be achieved in an alexa lambda function?  How do I pre-load the "on-deck" URL so it eventually plays without a gap?

Answer (score 1):

In your audioatream play command: pass it the URL to a m3u playlist that contains your glob of mp3 links.

This way it's one json package going to Alexa. Also note that the hyperlink to m3u must be https.

I saw somewhere in Alexa docs that it supports playlists.

The catch is that I believe you will receive a nearly finished event for each item in your playlist.

If your stuff is database driven, just create a CGI that returns a standard text html header and you can dynamically create your m3u on the fly, based on a token or unique Iyou'd you send down as part of your URL:

```
https://wackydimain.com/myscripts/dynamic_m3u.cgi?token=1234
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21098561)

Comment: @Rafael While the language is certainly hard to decipher, there is assuredly an answer here.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, and I have attempted what you describe using a single m3u file.  The problem is that the m3u data contains a list of audio file URLs, not the audio itself.  Even using a single m3u file, my tests show that the mp3 files specified still don't start loading from server until they are commanded to start playing.  (ie they don't start preloading while the previous track in playing, so we still get a buffer lag.)